# GridView with uniform column size

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I have this GridLayout:

```
        <!--back-->
        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:columnCount="5">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>
            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

        </GridLayout>
```

The images contained therein look like this:

[image]

How to make the images distribute on the screen in a uniform way, ie, occupy all the space until the end so that both have the same size?

Comment: Add title in English .

Comment: @ADM sorry for this

Comment: Your question is unclear you have more than one imageView but you are asking about only two images taking whole space.

Comment: @Prashant I mean, like, all the imageViews are organized evenly occupying the entire layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the limit for each box as follows:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

java Code :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

for kotlin try this :

```
// references to our images
private val mThumbIds = arrayOf<Int>(
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7)

class ImageAdapter(private val mContext: Context) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int = mThumbIds.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Any? = null

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = 0L

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val imageView: ImageView
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = ImageView(mContext)
            imageView.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(85, 85)
            imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8)
        } else {
            imageView = convertView as ImageView
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position])
        return imageView
    }
}
```

learn more about GridView : [Click this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#kotlin)

Answer (score 1):

Add the following attributes to all of the `imageView`s

```
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
```

For example:

```
 <GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:columnCount="5">

        <ImageView
           app:layout_columnWeight="1"
           app:layout_rowWeight="1" 
           android:src="@drawable/noTexture"/>

  ..............
```

Do as above to all `imageView`s.